# When I run my Android application in eclipse, i get this error

Tags: android

When i run my Android application i get the following in the error log

Message:

```
No command output when running: 'am start -n ru.startandroid.develop.p0031_ourfirstproject/ru.startandroid.develop.p0031_ourfirstproject.MainActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554
```

Exception Trace:

```
com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:430)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:347)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:610)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:67)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:109)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchAction(AndroidLaunchController.java:1293)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchAction(AndroidLaunchController.java:1305)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:1277)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:926)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:775)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:936)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:112)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps helped you.. 
Let me share so that some one can benefited...

In eclipse Increase the ADB connection timeout by following below steps

Window --> Preferences

Select Andriod -> DDMS from left panel

Increase value of "ADB connection time out (ms)"